# Office 2007 upgrade breaks 4GL Progress code

Tags: excel, office-2007, progress-4gl

I'm supporting some legacy 4GL Progress code.  One of our servers that runs 4GL was upgraded to Office 2007 without my knowledge (nice, right?).  Anyway, the upgrade broke a segment of code that's running the excel.application COM component.  Finance maintains a list of sales forecast numbers that they keep in an Excel document and the following code loads those numbers:

```
CREATE 
   "Excel.application" chExcelApplication NO-ERROR.
ASSIGN 
   chExcelApplication:VISIBLE = NO NO-ERROR.

ASSIGN 
   chWorkbook = chExcelApplication:Workbooks:OPEN(STRING(i-infile)) NO-ERROR.

ASSIGN
        chWorkSheet = chExcelApplication:Sheets:ITEM((1)) NO-ERROR.

IF input frame f-in Plan1 <> 0 THEN
    Plan1 = input frame f-in Plan1.
ELSE
    Plan1 = chWorkSheet:range(forecastColumn + "4"):VALUE.

IF input frame f-in Plan2 <> 0 THEN
    Plan2 = input frame f-in Plan2.
ELSE
   Plan2 = chWorkSheet:range(forecastColumn + "7"):VALUE.

IF input frame f-in Plan3 <> 0 THEN
   Plan3 = input frame f-in Plan3.
ELSE
   Plan3 = chWorkSheet:range(forecastColumn + "6"):VALUE.
```

When the code runs I get the following error:

"Invalid component-handle referenced while processing method/statement: Range."

The weird thing is that A) It doesn't fail on the "Open" command or the "Create" command - so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the COM object itself.  And B) if i run the same code from my machine that also runs Office 2007, it runs just fine.

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the contents of the excel into a new file, and it's pulling the numbers just fine now.  Weird...